# Webform and multiple memberships with same Member Organisation

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

When we create several membership types, with the same "Membership Organisation", it looks as if the previous membership has been replaced by the latest one. Assume we have two, MEM1 with 1 year membership at £30 and MEM2 with 2 year membership at £70.

1)Contact signs up for MEM1 fist, membership period is 1 year (June 2015 to May 2016 ), gets charged £30
2)Then signs up for MEM2, the membership period gets extended to 2 years (June 2015 to May 2017), gets charged £70

So what actually happens is, it does not track the memberships separately, and the contact seems to have lost the MEM1 membership.

Even if we were to consider "renewal with upsell" for this scenario, the contact should be charged only the difference in price and not the full price of MEM2, since the duration only gets extended.

Previously webform handled the membership types separately, so what will happen if we were to upgrade to the new version?

Also in civicrm we are still able to add more than one membership type for the same organisation.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you change the title to reflect the question better? EG CiviCRM Webform and multiple memberships with same Member Organisation.

Answer (score 4):

Currently you cannot use Webform-CiviCRM to sign members up for two membership types of the same organization concurrently, and this is true for the current release (4.10) and is unchanged in the upcoming v4.11.

What you described in your testing is working as designed. If a user signs up for type MEM1 and pays the fee, then comes back a year later and signs up for MEM2, it will change their membership type to MEM2, charge them the price for MEM2, and extend their expiration by a year. The only thing in your testing that made it look weird is that you did both of those things on the same day. Just wait a year between signups and it will make sense :)

If you do want to use a webform to sign members up for 2 different membership types, simply set them up in CiviCRM as belonging to different member organizations, and then the webform will understand it as a separate signup and not a renewal.